Update one column of one csv based on column from another in Python
I have two csv s like below :-
Master.csv



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




First
1001
Test1
1003


Second
1002
Test2
1004



Reference.csv



Code
Value




1001
Val1


1002
Val2


1003
Val3


1004
Val4



As can be seen  the Column2 and Column4 of Master.csv values are present in the same column Code of Reference.csv and I want to join the two csv to populate like below :-



Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4




First
Val1
Test1
Val3


Second
Val2
Test2
Val4



Please let me know it can be achieved through Python ..
I tried to join to csvs but unable to get the expected outputs.

What happens if no match?

The column of the first CSV is basically populated based on the columns from the second csv by a existing product process ,so there is no possibility of having no match....

Create DataFrames first by read_csv and use DataFrame.replace:
df1 = pd.read_csv('Master.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Reference.csv', index_col=['Code'])

out = df1.replace(df2['Value'])
print (out)
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0   First    Val1   Test1    Val3
1  Second    Val2   Test2    Val4

If need write to csv:
out.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

If need replace only columns from list:
df1 = pd.read_csv('Master.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Reference.csv', index_col=['Code'])

cols = ['Column2', 'Column4']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].replace(df2['Value'])

df1.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)


Thanks for your prompt answer . I tried the approach and it is creating the output csv but basically it is pasting the same content of Master csv to output csv and the update is not happening .

@UtsoDas - it means data are different data - strings vs integers

Thanks ,I changed the types of all cells in String while reading the csv and currently it is working ...Will test on more in this ..
